# Flutter drawArc() method draws full circle not just arc

Tags: dart, flutter

Using the latest flutter I would like to draw an arch from 0 to 10 using the `Canvas.drawArc` method. Here's what my code looks like:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double radius = 1000.0;
    final Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..color = Colors.blue[500]
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawArc(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width/2, size.height/2),
    10.0, 20.0, false, paint);
}
```

It's being drawn inside of a CustomPainter, and is called in the layout like this:

```
children: <Widget>[
        new CustomPaint(
          painter: new CircleGraphWidget(),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(
              'Here\'s text',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFFF),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
```

I expect the drawArc call to draw an arc within the rect from 10 to 20 on the circle, however this is what I get:

[image: Screenshot of full oval not arc]

I'm wondering what it takes to draw just a fraction of the oval instead of the whole thing. For instance, if I only wanted 1/4 of the circle drawn, how would I go about it?

Comment: What if you use `0.175, 0.349, ` as angle?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Weird that looks to be it. Any idea why? I can't find more info on the flutter docs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawArc.html

> It starts from startAngle radians around the oval up to startAngle + sweepAngle radians around the oval, with zero radians

It expects Radians instead of Degrees:

```
canvas.drawArc(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width/2, size.height/2),
0.175, 0.349, false, paint);
```

Comment: If you import `dart:math` you can use the constant `pi`. PI radians = 180 degrees. Rather counter-intuitively (to me anyway) the angle is measured *clockwise* from East. Example `canvas.drawArc(rect, pi / 4, pi * 3 / 4, close, paint);`

Comment: Dang I just got done working out all of my logic in degrees. This is going to suck(: Thanks a lot, all!

Comment: Why not just create a `deg2rad(...)` function?

Comment: `For future visitors`: [This library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/vector_math-library.html) from the official website can be used to convert degree to radian: `radians(double degrees) → double`, the formula is simple but it's good that we have it. :)

Comment: num _degreesToRads(num deg) {
    return (deg * pi) / 180.0;
  }

Answer (score 30):

## How to draw arcs

[image]

To paint in Flutter you use the [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget. The `CustomPaint` widget takes a [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) object as a parameter. In that class you have to override the `paint` method, which gives you a canvas that you can paint on. Here is the code to draw the arc in the image above.

```
// Don't forget: import 'dart:math' as math;

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(50, 100, 250, 200);
  final startAngle = -math.pi / 2;
  final sweepAngle = math.pi;
  final useCenter = false;
  final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 4;
  canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, useCenter, paint);
}
```

Notes:

- The `rect` is what the full oval would be inscribed within.
- The `startAngle` is the location on the oval that the line starts drawing from. An angle of 0 is at the right side. Angles are in radians, not degrees. The top is at 3π/2 (or -π/2), the left at π, and the bottom at π/2.
- The `sweepAngle` is how much of the oval is included in the arc. Again, angles are in radians. A value of 2π would draw the entire oval.
- If you set `useCenter` to true, then there will be a straight line from both sides of the arc to the center.

#### Context

Here is the *main.dart* code so that you can see it in context.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: HomeWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint( //                       <-- CustomPaint widget
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter { //         <-- CustomPainter class
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //                                             <-- Insert your painting code here.
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### See also

See [this article](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10) for my fuller answer.

Comment: how do you execute the paint method though ? didn't find an example for that , I get paint is never used and nothing but the space is painted

Comment: @yanivtwin, `paint` gets called when the HomeWidget is built. If you make your main.dart file be the bottom code and replace the `paint` method with the top code block it should work.

Comment: How can we make width of paint dynamic?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş, I don't think that is supported. You could probably draw two arcs to get that effect, though.